# How does the framework persist Notifications?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I've noticed that if I restart my phone, Android is able to restore all of the Notifications in my Status Bar.

However looking at Notifications, they contain a lot of things that are very hard to persist.  For instance they contain `PendingIntents` which may contain `Binder` objects, etc.

Is there a private API that is being used?  I'd love to see the source for this but can't find the correct piece of code in AOSP.

Comment: "I've noticed that if I restart my phone, Android is able to restore all of the Notifications in my Status Bar" -- if you run [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.10/Notifications/DownloadNotify) on a Nexus 5X, click the big Download button, wait for the notification to be displayed, then restart the phone, the notification does not appear on a restart. So, my guess is that the apps that you are testing all have `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` receivers and elect to re-raise their own notifications, if they had not been acted upon.

Comment: I think you're right.  I actually don't think the framework has persistent notifications ... just many apps have re-implemented this themselves.  Which is sad/impressive!

Comment: For a simple device reboot, one could argue that any outstanding notifications are likely still relevant. But if the device is powered off for any significant period of time, the OS would have no way of knowing which of those old notifications would still be relevant in their original form. Some of those notifications may be obsolete and require revision or removal. Plus, persistent notifications would put limits on what those notifications could trigger. So, Google took the simple (for them) solution, and I can't really blame them.

Comment: Agree (fwiw I work at Google but I don't work with the Android team),  I think the most developer-friendly thing to do would be to add a persistable option to the notification builder which would then restrict what other things you could add to the notification (for example no persisting playback notifications) but that's just me backseat driving!

Comment: "which would then restrict what other things you could add to the notification" -- the biggest limitation would be on what you can trigger via the overall tile or individual actions. `PendingIntent` is out, because it cannot be persisted while adhering to the `PendingIntent` contract. We could say that there is a `PersistablePendingIntent` that we could use, but then it can only work with exported components. One of the keys to `PendingIntent` is that it can work with non-exported components. Forcing things to be exported increases the attack surface. IOW, lotsa tradeoffs here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell the framework **does not** persist notifications.  There are just many apps that listen for reboot and re-post their notifications, which gave me that impression.

There's just no safe way to persist a Notification that contains `PendingIntent` and other similar objects.